# Алгоритм пересечения отрезков, заданных координатами

Tags: java, c#, c++, python, алгоритм

Как сделать такую задачу?

Входные даные:

1)N           //(количество прямых)

2)x1 y1 x2 y2 //(кординаты (х,у) начала и (х,у) конца прямой)

x1 y1 x2 y2 //(кординаты (х,у) начала и (х,у) конца второй прямой)
  и т.д.

Выходные даные:

1)количество пересечений прямых

Пример:

Входные:

5

1 1 7 7

4 0 0 4

99 100 99 200

2 0 2 2

99 199 99 199

Выходные:

2

---

Извините, речь об отрезках. Ошибся!

Comment: Уточните, речь о прямых или об отрезках? Если о прямых, то у них не бывает ни концов ни начал. Если об отрезках, то это получается совсем другая задача

Answer (score 2):

Каноническим, классическим решением задачи поиска всех пересечений в произвольном наборе отрезков является [алгоритм сканирующей прямой](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0). Весь алгоритм слишком громоздок, чтобы копировать его сюда, но в силу своей каноничности и фундаментальности в области вычислительной геометрии, его описание широко доступно.

Если величина `N` невелика, то вы можете обойтись и без сканирующих прямых, а просто перебрать все возможные пары отрезков и проверить их на пересечения. Это намного проще, но в общем случае будет очень неэффективно.

Answer (score 0):

В случае если подразумеваются отрезки, то вот отличная [статья](https://habr.com/post/267037/), объясняющая как решается эта задача.

В случае прямых достаточно найти угол между векторами, если он 0 или 180 градусов, то не пересекается, в ином случае прямые пересекаются. [Тут](http://edu.glavsprav.ru/info/ugol-mezhdu-vektorami/) написано как находить углы между векторами.

Comment: ну и не забыть отработать случай, когда три и больше прямых пересекаются в одной точке.

Answer (score 0):

Это работает, но если вводить как в примере - то вывод другой, онако я проверял вырисовывая картину, и у меня оказалось верно:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Введите N:");
            int n = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine());
    
            int[] x1 = new int[n];
            int[] x2 = new int[n];
            int[] y1 = new int[n];
            int[] y2 = new int[n];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.println((i+1) + ") Введите x1, y1, x2, y2:");
                String[] input =  s.nextLine().split(" ");
                x1[i] = Integer.valueOf(input[0]);
                y1[i] = Integer.valueOf(input[1]);
                x2[i] = Integer.valueOf(input[2]);
                y2[i] = Integer.valueOf(input[3]);
            }
            
            int intersects = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < x1.length; j++) {
                intersects += isIntersect(x1[i], y1[i], y2[i], x2[i], x1[j], y1[j], y2[j], x2[j]) ? 1 : 0;
                System.err.println(i + "-" + j);
            }
        }
            System.out.println("Кол-во пересечений:" + intersects);
            s.close();
        }
        
        private static boolean isIntersect(int x1, int y1, int y2, int x2,
                int x3, int y3, int y4, int x4) {
            int v1 = ((x4-x3)*(y1-y3)) - ((y4-y3)*(x1-x3));
            int v2 = ((x4-x3)*(y2-y3)) - ((y4-y3)*(x2-x3));
            int v3 = ((x2-x1)*(y3-y1)) - ((y2-y1)*(x3-x1));
            int v4 = ((x2-x1)*(y4-y1)) - ((y2-y1)*(x4-x1));
            return v1 * v2 < 0 && v3 * v4 < 0;
        }
```

---

## Проверка

---

Проверка из задания:

[image: Изображение для проверки]

Выдает: `4`

---

И проверка с таким вводом:

```
3
0 0 10 0
0 10 10 10
0 0 10 10
```

Выдает: `2`

[image: 3 0 0 10 0 0 10 10 10 0 0 10 10]

Comment: Об этом писал Ant - вычисление всех пересечений возможно, но для больших количеств отрезков нерационально.

Comment: Не спорю, но я просто написал код (разве плохо?), если вдруг кому-то понадобиться (мне вот понадобился). Но самое главное - это метод, который определяет пересекаются ли 2 отрезка, вот он, думаю, будет полезен. PS: формулу я взял с другого форума (по C++)